# How can I remove the "Waiting to install" icon from the Unity sidebar?

Tags: unity, software-center

The following icon got stuck in my sidebar after installing a software from the software center and stays there infinitely.

How can I remove the icon from the Unity sidebar?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I get your issue, some software is waiting to be installed, once it is finished, the icon will disappear. You are looking for a way to disable this from ever showing, permanently? or is it stuck there after installing software from the software center.

Comment: Indeed Mark! The icon got stuck there after installing a software from the software center. I will update my question.